# "None of us are" vs "none of us is"

Tags: grammar, plural-forms, pronouns, subject-verb-agreement

Which is correct?

> None of us are getting out of here alive.

or

> None of us is getting out of here alive.

Comment: If there's only one of something, or you can reasonably only expect one, you should probably use *is*: "none of us is going to be elected president." Otherwise, as in your sentence, you can use either "is" or "are".

Comment: @user3169: Hurray! Someone found a dupe for this!

Comment: Such a good link! Martha is likely to become happy and make it.